# <td class="table-time datet t1522665000-1-1-0-0">10:30</td>

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to this, and I cannot figure out how to get out the time value "10:30". I need to scrap a live score portal, I have managed to parse the games, results, and the odds, but I have no luck with the time value.   I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'time'
```

I think it is because the time is not declared like a string if i'm correct.

My code: Part I:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = options)
driver.get('http://www.oddsportal.com/matches/soccer/')

f = open("cote_today.txt", "w")
f.write(driver.page_source.encode("utf-8"))
f.close()
driver.quit()
```

Part II : Time func

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
f=open("cote_today.txt","r")
soup = BeautifulSoup(f, 'html.parser')
for table_participant in soup.find_all('td', class_='name table-participant'):
    print table_participant.get_text()

for result in soup.find_all('td', class_="center bold table-odds table-score"):
    print result.get_text()`enter code here`

time_start= soup.find('td', class_="table-time datet t1522666800-1-1-0-0").time
print time_start
```

Comment: result.text is what you wanted

Comment: no need to use BeautifulSoup here when selenium can locate any element and parse the text

Answer (score 0):

You can access "10:30" using `.text`

**Ex:**

```
time_start= soup.find('td', class_="table-time datet t1522666800-1-1-0-0")
print(time_start.text)
```